# Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell - Async Do de-sugars to synchronous?

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I'm working through Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell on the Overlapping Input/Output Chapter and I can't understand how async actually works asynchronously.

```
data Async a = Async (MVar a)

async' :: IO a -> IO (Async a)
async' action = do
  var <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO (do r <- action; putMVar var r)
  return (Async var)

-- if I desugar the do notation for async: 
async'' :: IO a -> IO (Async a)
async'' action = newEmptyMVar >>= \var ->
  (forkIO (action >>= \r -> putMVar var r)) >>
  (return $ Async var)

wait :: Async a -> IO a
wait (Async var) = readMVar var

blah = do
  a1 <- async'' (getURL "http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shovel")
  a2 <- async'' (getURL "http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spade")
  r1 <- wait a1
  r2 <- wait a2
  print (B.length r1, B.length r2)

-- if I desguar the above do block I get this, which looks
-- like a2 won't happen until a1 is finished?
blah' = async''(getURL "http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shovel") >>= \a1 ->
  async''(getURL "http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spade") >>= \a2 ->
  wait a1 >>= \r1 ->
  wait a2 >>= \r2 ->
  (print (B.length r1, B.length r2))
```

When I run this no matter what I do, Shovel always resolves before Spade. So how is this running async?  I would have expected interleaving sometimes (getting Spade before shovel).  Is my exampple just too fast and I'd see this behavior if I made many more examples?

Comment: If both tasks take about the same amount of time, then the first one to start *should* finish first. The first one gets a head start by virtue of being, well, the first one started.

Comment: Ok. I will mess around and change some urls to some longer ones, and add in a few more URLs.  I'm assuming the two `waits` at the end act like uhhh a single await in something like java or scala?  If a1 takes forever, and a2 finishes instantly, I'm still waiting until _everything_ finishes before printing the result as opposed to printing some intermediate result when a2 finished.

Comment: Yes, that's how `wait` works regardless of language. The process that started your program forked two additional processes, one for each URL, and then calls `wait` on `a1`. Once `a1` completes, it waits on `a2`, which may or may not have completed already. (If it did complete, the second `wait` can return immediately.)

Comment: handy hint from twitter on this "second thread depends on first thread handle. Not results of the computations, just the handles."

Answer (score 2):

> no matter what I do, Shovel always resolves before Spade.

Well, you always ask for the result of shovel before spade via that call to `wait` coming first.  You always start shovel before spade so it isn't surprising if it almost always resolves first too.

A simple test: use `threadDelay 100000 >> getURL "...shovel"` then look at the network traffic.  This will show you things are happening concurrently.